# Needing to get an object from an NSDictionary

Tags: objective-c

I have an NSDictionary that contains an array. What I am trying to do is get the object inside of the first part of my array photoDictionary:

```
-(NSString*) getImageAtIndex:(NSInteger *)index andObject:(PhotoPXArray *)photoArray {
    NSDictionary *photosDictionary = [MTLJSONAdapter JSONDictionaryFromModel:photoArray];
    NSArray = [[photosDictionary objectAtIndex:0];
   //NSArray *photoCollection = [MTLJSONAdapter JSONArrayFromModels:self.photoPXArray];

    return @"ff";
}
```

This should be really simple but I am banging my head against a wall.

My ultimate goal is to get the 'image_url' as shown in this object model:

[image]

Comment: NSLog the dictionary, or, in the console window, do `po photosDictionary`.  This will show you a much more legible view of the dictionary.  But there's nothing complicated above -- you have a dictionary containing an entry whose value is an array of dictionaries.  The first array element's dictionary contains an element named "image_url" whose value is a string.  `NSString* url = photosDictionary[@"photos"][0][@"image_url"];`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Hot Licks answer was PERFECT!!

NSString* url = photosDictionary[@"photos"][0][@"image_url"];